# How to transform sigmoid such that it approaches this piecewise function in the limit

Tags: calculus

I would like a parameter or transformation to toggle to interpolate between a standard sigmoid function and the following piecewise function:

$(x_1, x_2)$ : $f(x) \mid x \in (x_1, x_2)$

1. $(-5)$: $f(x) \in (-\infty, 0)$
2. $(-5, +5)$: $f(x) = 0$
3. $(+5)$: $f(x) \in (0, +\infty)$

The property I'm interested in is controlling how quickly the f(x) "ramps up" away as x moves away from 0.

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about a sigmoid function, $f: R \to R$,  are you talking about function like

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+ e^{-wx + b}}  \ \  \ \ \ \textrm{for}\  w, b \in R $$

[image]

For this type of function, as you can see, I can make $f$ ramp up as fast as I want by controlling the parameter $w$, and $b$ to shift the function.